# Overriding ArrayAdapter.Add

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I want to override the .add method of Android's `ArrayAdapter` class.  However the compiler is unable to resolve the type T.  I've googled until my fingers hurt for a solution. Can anyone shine a light for me?  Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public void add(T object)
{
return super.add(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your class definition look like? It should probably be something like:

```
public class MyAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

  @Override
  public void add(T object)
  {
    super.add(object);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the T type in the subtype declaration like this:

```
public class SubTypeAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {


    public SubTypeAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override public void add(T object) {
        super.add(object);
    }
}
```

You also want to note that the add() method doesn't return a value, so you should remove the return keyword the return super.add(object); line.

Comment: You're very welcome, and all the best with your app development :)